"mainwindow.cpp" includes the uic file "ui_mainwindow.h", but the user interface file "mainwindow.ui" could not be found in the following directories
Below is my desired folder structure :
MyProject
  CMakeLists.txt

  include
       mainwindow.h

  src
       mainwindow.cpp
       main.cpp

  forms
       mainwindow.ui

This is my desired folder structure. Below is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MyProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

# Add the ui files
qt6_wrap_ui(UI_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/forms/mainwindow.ui
)

# Include the directories
include_directories(INCLUDE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mainwindow.cpp
        ${UI_FILES}
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(MyProject
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET MyProject APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(MyProject SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(MyProject
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

# Include the forms directory
target_link_libraries(MyProject PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.MyProject)
endif()
set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS MyProject
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(MyProject)
endif()

I set out to achieve two things when I made the CMake file this way:

In my cpp file, I should be able to

#include "mainwindow.h"

instead of
#include "../include/mainwindow.h"

This was achieved as my main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp has the desired include.

To achieve this folder structure, but the below is the error:

"SRC:/src/mainwindow.cpp"
includes the uic file "ui_mainwindow.h",
but the user interface file "mainwindow.ui"
could not be found in the following directories
  "SRC:/src"

Note : I am using QT Creator.

On the one side you use cmake automoc (set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)) but then you do the uic stuff by yourself (qt6_wrap_ui(UI_FILES) which is wrong - only use one of them. Since you use a custom layout for your ui & src organization, you might only be able to use qt6_wrap_ui() and not automoc.

Maybe also setting https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS.html#prop_tgt:AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS to the appropriate folder helps to make AUTOUIC work.
